# Overriding unique indexed values

Tags: php, mysql

This is what I'm doing right now (`name` is `UNIQUE`):

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE name='apple';
```

> Check if the query returned any
>   result.  If yes, don't do anything. If
>   no, a new value has to be inserted:

```
INSERT INTO fruits (name) VALUES ('apple');
```

Instead of the above is it ok to insert the value into the table without checking if it already exists? If the name already exists in the table, an error will be thrown and if it doesn't, a new record will be inserted.

Right now I am having to insert 500 records in a for loop, which results in 1000 queries. Will it be ok to skip the "already-exists" check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the IGNORE feature:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO fruits VALUES ('apple')
```

If there is a key violation, it just skips this value

Answer (score 2):

check out

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ...
```

and

```
INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

Thes second method is preferred as the IGNORE statement simply causes mysql to issue warning instead of error

Comment: The second method is *not* preferred as OP wants a duplicate entry to be skipped, not updated.

Comment: yeah but it can easily be updated to itself as set `apple` = `apple`