# INSERT if PRIMARY KEY is not present, IGNORE if present

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overriding unique indexed values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060458/overriding-unique-indexed-values)

I want to create a MySQL Query which do INSERT only if the PRIMARY KEY is NOT present, and IGNORE if present.

Here is the table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  uid bigint NOT NULL,
  frnd1_uid bigint,
  frnd2_uid bigint,
  frnd3_uid bigint,
  set_date date NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT user_uid PRIMARY KEY (uid )
);
```

Comment: You want [`INSERT IGNORE INTO tablename (...) VALUES (...)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : Thanks! I am actually a very beginner of Databases.